# useSelector state returns undefined but the redux dev tool showing the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am fetching data from api and then store some detail in redux store and from redux store I am setting some values on browser localstorage.

I am using browser localstorage for conditional statement but because of undefined in or initial state inside the redux store my condtions are not executing.

My code:

```
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isAuth } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const submitLoginForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginPending());
    const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44316/api/auth/login", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      })
    });
    
    if(response.status === 200){
      dispatch(loginSuccess());
      debugger;
      localStorage.setItem('auth',isAuth);
      console.log(isAuth);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
    }
    else{
      dispatch(loginFailed());
    }
  };

  if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')) === true){
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="formContainer">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={submitLoginForm}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
              We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

My slice Contain:

```
loginSuccess: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isAuth = true;
      state.error = "";
    }
```

I want to get isAuth value from redux store and then store it inside the browser local storage. But I am getting `false` value in my console

In the browser redux dev tool its showing the state change.

[image]

Comment: Where is the portion of the code which sets `isAuth` on action dispatch? Can we see that part?

Comment: Actuall I didn't put my slice code. When I make a call of ```dispatch(loginSuccess());``` isAuth is update with ```true```

Comment: Here Is my loginSucess code:

```
loginSuccess: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isAuth = true;
      state.error = "";
    }
```

Comment: Please, update your question with the whole redux logic regarding `isAuth` state

Comment: updated please check

Comment: Can you by any change put your code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) so we can test it ourselves